# Transpose a table using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have some data in a table which I want to transpose using SQL. here is the sample data.

```
create table test_pivot(
Name varchar2(100),
DeptA varchar2(50),
DeptB varchar2(50),
DeptC varchar2(50),
DeptD varchar2(50)
);

insert all 
into test_pivot(Name,DeptA,DeptB,DeptC,DeptD)
values('Asfakul','Y',NULL,NULL,NULL)
into test_pivot(Name,DeptA,DeptB,DeptC,DeptD)
values('Debmalya',NULL,'Y',NULL,NULL)
into test_pivot(Name,DeptA,DeptB,DeptC,DeptD)
values('Ranjan',NULL,NULL,'Y',NULL)
into test_pivot(Name,DeptA,DeptB,DeptC,DeptD)
values('santanu',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Y')
select 1 from dual;
```

I want the data to be displayed like below..

[image]

I am having a tough time figuring it out. please  let me know.

Comment: You know you want to pivot, so how far have you got with the pivot operator? Or are you still on an older version that doesn't support that?

Comment: I think it's UNPIVOT operation. I am still trying.

Answer (score 2):

Here an SELECT statement without PIVOT and UNPIVOT. As you can see, it's far more complex:

```
select dept,
       nvl(max(case when name = 'Asfakul' then dept_val end), 'N') as Asfakul,
       nvl(max(case when name = 'Debmalya' then dept_val end), 'N') as Debmalya,
       nvl(max(case when name = 'Ranjan' then dept_val end), 'N') as Ranjan,
       nvl(max(case when name = 'santanu' then dept_val end), 'N') as santanu 
  from(select name,
              dept,
              case when dept = 'depta' then depta
                   when dept = 'deptb' then deptb
                   when dept = 'deptc' then deptc
                   when dept = 'deptd' then deptd
               end dept_val
         from test_pivot
         join(select 'depta' as dept from dual union all
              select 'deptb' as dept from dual union all
              select 'deptc' as dept from dual union all
              select 'deptd' as dept from dual
             ) 
           on 1 = 1
      ) 
 group 
    by dept
 order
    by dept
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DB version supports pivot and unpivot then you can use the same.
See the below query, I think this should help you..

```
SELECT * 
  FROM(  SELECT * 
           FROM test_pivot 
        UNPIVOT (Check_val FOR DEPT IN (DEPTA, DEPTB, DEPTC, DEPTD))
      )
 PIVOT(MAX(check_val) FOR NAME IN ('Asfakul' AS Asfakul, 
                                   'Debmalya' AS Debmalya, 
                                   'Ranjan' AS Ranjan, 
                                   'santanu' AS santanu))
 ORDER BY dept;
```

---

Comment: Thanks. But can we do the same using sql Only?

Comment: How can we implement using the same sql.. Can you guide

Comment: Thanks all for helping :)